Can't install igraph 1.2.6 in R 3.6.3 on Windows because libxml/encoding.h can't be found
I have been trying to install igraph as a part of a larger lock file that was given to me. The lock file specifically needs the 1.2.6 version probably for the functionality of other packages (I'm not very sure). I have previously encountered the same problem with glpk but was able to resolve it by downloading and installing the package, and putting the header file in both Path and CPATH variables. This is the error that shows right now:
To run the lock file, I use
renv::restore()

The other packages install with no problem, but I am stuck with the error below with igraph:

foreign-graphml.c:40:29: fatal error: libxml/encoding.h: No such file or directory (https://stackoverflow.com) #include <libxml/encoding.h>
^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:208: foreign-graphml.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'igraph'<

I have tried the solution I used for glpk by downloading the Windows version of libxml2 through this link and then putting the libxml/encoding.h directory both in the Path and CPATH variables of my laptop. However, it is not working.
Thanks in advance for your help!

I can't give a response from the top of my head, but generally my advice would be: (1) Newer versions of igraph have many bugs fixed. If you see a difference in behaviour between old and new, it's likely the result of a bugfix, with the new behaviour being correct. So try to use the latest version (2) If you insist on compiling the old version, it'll likely be much easier on Linux than Windows, where there are standard locations for libraries such as libxml2.
